# Select range with for Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to correct this code please.
Sheet 1 =`combine`,
sheet 2 to 10 my data sheet.
I want copy selected data to `combine` sheet.

What I tried to do:

select data range from `sheet2` using input box and I want to copy same range from other sheets into `combined` .

```
Sub sheetmerge()

Dim combine As Worksheet
Dim arange As Range

    Set combine = Sheets(1)
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Set arange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the range", Type:=8)
    arange.Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=combine.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(x).Activate
    Range(arange).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=combine.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: More on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926037/applying-range-modifications-in-multiple-sheets/48926436#48926436).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub SheetMerge()
    Dim combine As Worksheet, rngToCopy As Range

    Set combine = Worksheets(1)
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Set rngToCopy = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the range", Type:=8)
    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=combine.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For x = 3 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(x).Range(rngToCopy.Address).Copy Destination:=combine.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next x
End Sub
```